# How is a Rails Engine different from just a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm reading this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Sounds great.  I'm not complaining.  But the examples shown I think I can do with just a normal ruby gem.  What can a Rails Engine do that a Ruby gem can't?

That may be a bad way to phrase the question.  What is an example of something that is easy to do with a Rails Engine that would be hard to do with just a Ruby gem?

Answer (score 0):

A gem is a bundled up piece of code that makes it easy to distribute code, especially open source projects and plugins. A rails engine is basically a mini rails app that is either mounted or included in a parent rails project. Some rails engines (quite common) as distributed using gems. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is an example of this.